# How to implement a custom DataType in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a fairly simple trait and some case objects that extend it. Nothing fancy. I am currently writing a new data source using the Data Source V2 API and I want to create a custom `DataType` for that construct.

Currently I have this:

```
class ChannelGroupType extends DataType {

  val defaultSize: Int = 1
}
```

Now I am stuck. What do I additionally have to do to convert this to some internal representation and back? How do I actually link this to my `ChannelGroup` trait and case objects?

Is there a tutorial on how to implement a custom type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my perspective looks like you don't have to implement your own `DataType`. The following flow for creating a data source with `DataSourceV2` shall solve your problem. Advanced examples with transactions, DB for `DataSourceV2` you can find in [this project](https://github.com/phatak-dev/spark2.0-examples/tree/389cdb42c850862c027f7bbce08f201cb25c2374/src/main/scala/com/madhukaraphatak/examples/sparktwo/datasourcev2), the repo corresponds to the explanation in [this blog](http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/spark-datasource-v2-part-1/). IMO following these tutorials is the most straightforward solution in your case.

P.S.
If the usage of *Data Source V1* is enough for you, you can find the specific implementation in [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/7997c3c184d3ad30a0fa6615188a289e99df69be/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/csv/CsvRelation.scala#L104) project by Databricks. 
`spark-csv`is a mature project, so you can rely on patterns in this project.

P.S.S. 
If you want to create own *User Defined Type* it's not feasible at this moment, this API were closed and will be released to the public in Spark 3.0, you can follow up a ticket [SPARK-7768](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7768).